# Using a string to access an element of a form

Tags: .net, winforms, c++-cli

I'm building a form in Visual Studio 2012, and I have a controller (a slider to be more specific) called `trFinger1Ph1`. Is it possible to access this using a variable?

This is how I normally access my control (which works)

```
int value = Form1::trFinger1Ph1-> Value;
```

But I am hoping to do this:

```
std::string test = "trFinger1Ph1"
int value = Form1::test -> Value;
```

I am using this because I have a large list of controls, and accessing them this way would help me clean up a large portion of my code. 
It is evident that the program is looking inside of trFinger1Ph1 for test, and not recognizing it as the variable test.

Any ideas?

Comment: the *a::b* operator asks for the member b of the object a, so you are asking for the member *test* from the object *a*.As the string test is an object outside *Form1*, this results in an error.If you want to perform literal substitution in your code then you would need a macro, but this is highly discouraged. If you want to call them for their name you need to create a method inside the object *Form1*, such that it links each literal string to a function.

Comment: I have to wonder why you've used `static` members to store handles to controls.  Normally each instance of the same form has its own instance of the control.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't do that. You can in PHP and some other languages, but it not possible in C or C++ (this also applies to many other languages)

The name of a variable will "disappear" when the code is compiled.

You may be able to do something else that solves the problem (as I suspect this is an XY question - you are asking how to do Y because you have problem X, and you think doing Y is the right way to solve it). For example, you could have a table containing names as strings, and a reference to the relevant object that this refers to, and then use the table to look up the string, and use the reference to get the value. I'm no expert on "Forms" however...

Comment: At this rate I'm going to owe you a couple boxes of Twinkies.

Comment: In WinForms, container controls already maintain a collection of each of their child controls. You access it through the `Controls` property.

Answer (score 2):

Mats Petersson and Captain Oblivious are both correct in their answers that you cannot do this. There is no way in C++ to access a variable or object by a string that contains it name.

However, there *is* a way in WinForms to access a control on a form if all you have is a string that contains its name. You do this using the [`Controls` collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controls.aspx) maintained by the parent form.

You can manually iterate through this collection using a `for each` loop, comparing the value of the `Name` property of each control to your string object until you get a match:

```
for each (Control ^ctl in this->Controls)
{
    if (ctl->Name == "trFinger1Ph1")
    {
        // Found a match!
        // ...
    }
}
```

…or you can use the [`Find` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find.aspx) to let the framework do the searching for you and return an array that contains all possible matches.

```
var ctrls = this.Controls.Find("trFinger1Ph1", true);
```

Unfortunately, you cannot do it using the syntax you propose. That is:

```
std::string test = "trFinger1Ph1"
int value = Form1::test -> Value;  // won't work!
```

Obviously, you need to ensure that all of your controls have a unique name in order for this to work. And it's kind of a [design smell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell), something that looks very suspicious and is probably wrong. I would not advise this as a general way of "cleaning up" your code like you suggest in the question.

Comment: The `Controls.Find` example is written in C#.  Of course, it's possible to do the same thing in C++/CLI, but that particular code won't work as-is.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access a variable that way in C++.

If you *really* want to access them via a string literal you can create a `std::map` and populate it with pointers or references to the various member variables.

```
std::map<std::string, ControlType&> controls;
controls.insert(std::pair<std::string, ControlType&>("xyz", Form::trFinger1Ph1);

controls["xyz"].Value = somevalue;
```

I don't think that is going to make your code any cleaner though. Another way is to simply declare a reference to the control.

```
ControlType& control1 = Form::trFinger1Ph1;

control1.Value = somevalue;
```